# Array length is zero but Array is not empty

Tags: javascript, arrays

When I'm trying to iterate through an array, get it's length or access indexes I'm getting Error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`.

The array isn't empty and when I `console.log()` it I've gotten.

```
0: {user_id: 11, …}
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

I see that **proto**: Array(0) and I'm assuming this means it's a 0 length Array but how do I make it non-zero length so that I can iterate through it?

Code for reference:

```
useEffect(() => {
     blog.authors.map(data => {
         console.log(data)
      })
}, [blog])
```

I've also tried. It worked, but I immediately got the similar error.

```
useEffect(() => {
        (async() => {
            await blog.authors.map(data => {
                console.log(data)
            })
        })()
}, [blog])
```

Comment: `.map()` returns a new array; what are you expecting?

Comment: `__proto__: Array(0)` means the object inherits from `Array.prototype` which is an empty array. It says nothing about the length of the object itself, which is `1`.

Comment: `.map()` is just as example. It doesn't work as indexing In this array or something else. `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

Comment: The error "*cannot read property 'map' of undefined*" means that `blog.authors` itself is `undefined`. Probably it's still loading or something? Notice that your effect might be called multiple times. Probably an `if (blog.authors) blog.authors.forEach(console.log)` should suffice.

Comment: Bergi knows what he is talking about, try his code it will help with your understanding

Comment: Oh actually it wasn't as hard as I expected. Sorry for inattention. Thanks!

Comment: The console.log is async, if you log an object that at a later time is populated you get the updated value. So, blog.authors doesn't exist when you try to map it, and it is populated later. That value comes from a request or something?

Comment: I've solved it! Bergi helped me. The solution was very easy as checking if blog.authors isn't undefined. blog.authors is redux state. Apologize for inattention, I should try it earlier.

Comment: Set the array to empty by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple checking if `blog.authors` isn't undefined solved it.

Answer (score -2):

No, array indexes are `0 based`.

```
var arr = ['a', 'b'];
console.log(arr.length); // => 2
console.log(arr[0]);     // => a
```

So instead of making confusing assertion about what works and not without providing the code them providing other code, could you just see the result of that:

```
useEffect(() => {
     console.log({blog});
     console.log({authors: blog.authors });
     blog.authors.map(data => {
         console.log(data)
      })
}, [blog])
```

Because I suspect that `blog` changed overtime, having some authors and something authors undefined.

Comment: You have two separate `useEffect`, one that fetch the data and set it to state and one that console.log from the state. And no initial value in `useState` ? Right? If you provide the full code, we can give you a full answer, just an `if` is a bug fix, not a real solution.

Comment: The real answer is to check if blog.authors isn't undefined. I had to check it earlier but missed it. The blog.authors is redux state.